# syntaxerror: simple ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data with ajax, but I get a syntaxerror, and I don't understand why...
I read some topics with the same issue but I still don't understand where is my mistake...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "imprime_planning",
    data: {
        "test": "test"
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(res, status, exeption) {
        alert(res);
        console.log(exeption);
    }
});
```

thanks for your expert eyes !!

EDIT :
the "syntaxerror" is given in the error function by the exception

Comment: Where are you getting the syntax error? Which line number

Comment: And don't see any syntax error in your code.

Comment: What is that syntax error... post those error...

Comment: Since your code itself us syntactically correct, I can only assume that the JSON you get as response is invalid. The question does not contain enough information to be answered properly. Syntax error questions are off-topic most of the time anyway.

Comment: it is the error function that give me that syntaxerror, in the next page, I don't get any post data

Comment: in the error function, the status is "parsererror" and the exception is "SyntaxError {} "

Comment: Then the issue is likely in your JSON, as it's a "parseerror" - meaing the javascript engine was unable to parse the JSON.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZMN8/

It's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote this test.php for clarification:

test.php:

```
<?php
    $res = array(); 
    $res['answer'] = "got POST request with test: ".$_POST['test'];
    print(json_encode($res));
?>
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
         "test": "test"
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg.answer);
        console.log(msg.answer);
    },
    error: function(res, status, exeption) {
        alert(res);
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

works for me...

Comment: thanks for you answer, I get : {}

When I try : console.log(res.responseText);
I get what I'm expecting, but my next page doesn't receive post data

Comment: are you sure you are not missing .php extension in the URL? can you post how you are trying to get the data on the next page?

Comment: I'm using cakephp, the url are rewritted.
I use a debug($this->request->data) which is supposed to display data received in the page (post, get or whatever), I get an empty array.
But that make sense since my ajax request still throw the error function, I guess...

Comment: please note your ajax call will go to error also when not able to parse response from the page, in this case it expects json response.

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't realize I had to get a json response from my target.
So your example works fine, but I guess I should use post() instead of ajax().
Thank you for your patience.

Comment: you're welcome, just fyi, ajax call response type is configured by the dataType field. can take (xml, json, script, or html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're setting Response.StatusCode to something other than 200. Write your exception's message using Response.Write, then use...

```
xhr.responseText
```

...in your javascript.

Refer below link for guidelines....

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/

Comment: I don't understand what's happening...
I display res.responseText in the error function and it seems to be what I expect, but when I go to the page in the url, my POST is empty...

Comment: i did't understand what are you expecting on Post ? your problem soved right!!!

Comment: Solved ?
I don't received post data, I'm expecting nothing but an explanation.